# SQL Server Query Compilation - Converting VarChar to Float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting some strange behaviour from SQL Server. I have an underlying view that returns an amount field. That amount field is casting from VARCHAR(50) to FLOAT.

I can **successfully** run the following query:

```
SELECT AMOUNT
FROM vReturnDetails
```

I can also **successfully** run the following query:

```
SELECT AMOUNT
FROM vReturnDetails v 
    INNER JOIN MyTable t 
        ON t.LicenceNumber = v.LicenceNumber
        AND t.ReturnYear = v.ReturnYear 
WHERE t.ReturnYear = 2012
```

Similarly I **can** run this query:

```
SELECT AMOUNT
FROM vReturnDetails v 
    INNER JOIN MyTable t 
        ON t.LicenceNumber = v.LicenceNumber
        AND t.ReturnYear = v.ReturnYear 
WHERE t.ReturnYear <> 2012
```

This is where it gets strange though, I **cannot** run either of the following:

```
SELECT AMOUNT
FROM vReturnDetails v 
    INNER JOIN MyTable t 
        ON t.LicenceNumber = v.LicenceNumber
        AND t.ReturnYear = v.ReturnYear 
WHERE t.ReturnYear = 2012 OR t.ReturnYear <> 2012

SELECT AMOUNT
FROM vReturnDetails v 
    INNER JOIN MyTable t 
        ON t.LicenceNumber = v.LicenceNumber
        AND t.ReturnYear = v.ReturnYear
```

I can **successfully** run this query though:

```
SELECT AMOUNT
FROM vReturnDetails v 
    INNER JOIN MyTable t 
        ON t.LicenceNumber = v.LicenceNumber
        AND t.ReturnYear = v.ReturnYear 
WHERE t.ReturnYear <> 2013 --2013 is a dummy value that doesn't exist
```

Can anyone shed any light on what is happening under the covers here. It makes no sense at all to me so I'm not sure where to start looking to fix the problem.

The error I am receiving is

*Error converting data type varchar to float.*

This is on Sql Server 2008 SP2

Comment: what datatype are your fields?

Comment: Sorry, LicenceNumber is a VARCHAR(20) and ReturnYear is an INT. As mentioned Amount is a FLOAT and is CONVERTed from VARCHAR(50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server is complicated.  The order of processing in the SQL engine is not necessarily the same as the order in the query.  Filters in WHERE clauses, for instance, can be applied when the data is read, or later after the data is processed.

Clearly, you have some values in the AMOUNT field that are not valid floats.  The simplest explanation is that when you ran:

```
SELECT AMOUNT
FROM vReturnDetails
```

You did not return all the rows . . . and the row with the bad data was later.

Alternatively, vReturnDetails is a view based on underlying data, some of which is bad.  When the query is compiled, it might affect where the filtering occurs.  In some cases, the engine might decide to read all the data, do the conversion, and then continue -- but it gets an error in the conversion disrupting the process.

You can fix this by changing the view to something like:

```
select (case when isnumeric(amountstr) = 1 then cast(amountstr as float) end) as Amount
```

SQL Server *does* guarantee the order of evaluation in a case statement.  So, this should not return an error.

ISNUMERIC() and CONVERT to FLOAT are not fully consistent.  I know ISNUMERIC accepts commas and dollar signs (and maybe other characters).  You can also try this (assuming you are using US-style formats for numbers):

```
select (case when isnumeric(amountstr) = 1
             then cast(replace(replace(amountstr, ',', ''), '$', '') as float) end) as Amount
```

Comment: I can assure you that I did wait for the query to finish, which is why I am posting the question :) I also tried changing the line to be **        CASE WHEN IsNumeric(a.Answer) = 1 THEN CONVERT(FLOAT, a.Answer) ELSE NULL END as Amount ** and the result was the same. I also tried using CAST instead of CONVERT...the rsult was the same every time.

Comment: @AdamEmerton . . . Do you know what the bad data looks like?  It could be an issue of an out-of-range value or when isnumeric() is wrong.  For instance, '1,123' and '$1,123' are both "isnumeric() = 1" but cause the conversion to fail.

Comment: What is strange is if I change the underlying view to just return the unmodified value, it works as expected (but because of other dependencies this isn't an option). If I add a condition to the WHERE clause of AND IsNumeric(AMOUNT) = 0, I get 378 rows back...all of which are NULLs...and CONVERT(FLOAT, NULL) is valid.

Comment: Your theory on the execution order was correct. The where clause of my consuming query was being applied at the same time as the view resulting in invalid data coming back. The view is responsible for filtering out rows that are not applicable, but SQL managed to optimise my query and try and delay that filtering until after the convert, which caused the error. Thanks :) It would be nice if I could also apply a hint to the view to ensure it is fully executed before being used by other queries.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing as to where the CONVERT is being called, in your query. From your comment above, I understand that AMOUNT is VARCHAR(50). Where are you converting it to FLOAT?

Comment: The convert is in the underlying view (vReturnDetails)
    SELECT --Bunch of other fields,
    Convert(float,a.Answer) as Amount,
    FROM MyTable t INNER JOIN MyOtherTable a ON a.ReturnID = t.ReturnID 
    --WHERE clause

Comment: Ah! I didn't get this from the question above. Anyways, I think there are one or more records in the portion of the table for which this query is failing. I would remove the conversion for now and try to drill down those offending records, by narrowing down the search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a convert in an underlying view as mentioned, there is only a possibility of bad data causing the query to fail. Do you have null values by any chance? 
have you tried using the IsNull() function on the amount so that any null/ bad data is zeroed out?